# mysql PHP login system accepts any password sent from Unity

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a login system in Unity, and it works to login with a username from the database, but the login is successful no matter what I type into the password field. I don't understand why, as I thought this code would check whether the password match with the username or not. Any clues? I'm btw very new to PHP. Thanks :)

**php code:**

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM unitytut WHERE `user`='$user'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)){
if($pass = $row['pass']){
    die("login-SUCCESS");
    }
    }
```

**unity code:**

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("user", user);
        form.AddField ("pass", pass);
        WWW w = new WWW ("http://mywebpage.dx.am/Login.php", form);
            StartCoroutine (Login (w));


   IEnumerator Login(WWW w){
        yield return w;
        if (w.error == null) {
            if(w.text == "login-SUCCESS"){
       Debug.Log("LOGIN SUCCESS");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is your problem, you're using a single `=`, because of this `$pass` is being set, which will return true, use a double `==` instead, as this is for checking if its equal to.

So this:

```
if($pass = $row['pass']){
    die("login-SUCCESS");
}
```

Should be this:

```
if($pass == $row['pass']){
    die("login-SUCCESS");
}
```

Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you might want to look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: that was a silly mistake. I'm still confused when it comes to php compared to c#, still got a lot to learn but obviously this solved my problem. Thank you very much :)